# how to extract userId values from below response using RegEx

Tags: regex, jmeter

How to extract `userId` values from below code response using RegEx

```
{"errorId":0,"errorLongDesc":"Data Successfully saved","errorDesc":"success","user":{"userId":3706}}
```

Comment: Use JSON parser. Don't parse with regex. http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/

Comment: var x = {"errorId":0,"errorLongDesc":"Data Successfully saved","errorDesc":"success","user":{"userId":3706}};
console.log(x.user.userId)

Comment: Thnaks Nhahtdh,I am new to Jmeter,Dosent know how to use JSON parser.Could you please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not advisable to do it via regex, but if you  find no other option:

```
(?<="userId":)\d+
```

demo here: https://regex101.com/r/kZ4tQ7/2

Comment: Thanks for the help aelor.but the URL shared is not accessible